# HTML5 input=time won't set via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a problem with an HTML5 form field, I need the field (time) to update each second to the current time, the update code is called every second via a setInterval, the HTML5 form element :

```
<form name="process">
    <input name="p_time" type="time" value="<?php echo date("H:i:s");?>" />
    //...
</form>
```

when I try to update : **document.forms.process.p_time.value = current.time.slice(17,25);** the display remains at the setting made by PHP, the type of string data is the same format of 00:00:00 but it refuses to budge from that original time. the variable current.time is a string of the UTC format corresponding to : **ddd, dd mmm, yyyy hh:mm:ss +00:00 GMT** variety.

The javascript is a simple routine, it updates a

element in the full version

```
current = {
    now:function(){ return new Date(); },
    time:0,
    tick:function(){
        current.time = current.now().toUTCString();
        document.forms.process.p_time.value = current.time.slice(17,25);
        current.clock();
    },
    clock:function(){
        current.target.innerHTML = current.time.slice(0,25);
    },
    auto:setInterval(current.tick,1000)
}
```

What I don't want to have to do is to have the page refreshed by a page refresh.

Comment: What browser are you using? The time input type is not supported in  FireFox, IE and Safari.

Comment: Using Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m

Answer (score 2):

This should work!: http://jsfiddle.net/d9vg5yhL/1/

```
<form name="process">
    <input name="p_time" id='time' type="time" value="" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function startTime() {
    var today=new Date();
    var h=today.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();
    h = checkTime(h); 
    m = checkTime(m);
    s= checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('time').value = h+":"+m+":"+s;
    var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},1000);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i<10) {i = "0" + i} // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}

startTime();
```